# ssl certificate generated by mkcert is not a full chain

Tags: node.js, ssl, mkcert

I am using [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to generate a self signed certificate for localhost.

```sh
mkcert -install
mkcert localhost
```

This works fine for the browser but if I try and and do a fetch from node, I get this error:

> FetchError: request to https://localhost:52882/ failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

I think this is because mkcert is not creating the full chain.

I have hacked around this by using the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable.

```
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="$(mkcert -CAROOT)/rootCA.pem"
```

and I know there is the `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` nuclear approach but I am curious to know how this can be fixed without these.

Comment: Have you tried just manually concatenating the chain/root with the domain-cert into 1 file and using that?

Comment: I love the nuclear approach

Answer (score 9):

It is working perfectly. You have own certificate authority (CA) and that one issues `localhost` certificate directly. There is no intermediate certificate authority used, so assumption `mkcert is not creating the full chain` is not correct.

CA cert must be available on your machine and you need to define, which CA certs are trustworthy. `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` is exactly that config, where you can allow particular CA cert file.

Of course you can add this custom CA cert to system CA cert stores. Their locations depend on used OS, e.g.:

```
   "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",                // Debian/Ubuntu/Gentoo etc.
    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt",                  // Fedora/RHEL 6
    "/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem",                            // OpenSUSE
    "/etc/pki/tls/cacert.pem",                           // OpenELEC
    "/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem", // CentOS/RHEL 7
    "/etc/ssl/cert.pem",                                 // Alpine Linux
```

That should be done by `mkcert -install`.

My guess is that your node is not using system CA store (env variable `NODE_OPTIONS=--use-openssl-ca`), so only node's own CA certs (e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.0.0/src/node_root_certs.h) are trustworthy for the node.

You have option to use system CA cert store (env variable `NODE_OPTIONS=--use-openssl-ca` or node CLI parameter `--use-openssl-ca`) or you can allow your custom CA with env variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` as you did.